# Is there a way to follow a link based in its text in email_spec?

Tags: rspec, email-spec

In RSpec I can easily follow the link corresponding to certain text using

```
click_link "change your password"
```

RSpec will then find the appropriate link and follow the associated HREF.

#### How do you do this in an email?

I'm trying to execute the same behaviour in an email using `email_spec`. However I can't seem to find an equivalent helper that will click a link corresponding to particular link text in the [email_spec helpers](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/email_spec/EmailSpec/Helpers).

This seems like a pretty obvious use-case so before I write something to do it for me I wanted to check whether one already exists.

The scenario is that I want to follow whatever link in the email corresponds to "Change my password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you have the email_spec properly installed and the helper modules included in your spec or your spec_helper.rb file.  If you did this, the proper methods would be available in your test.  You then need to open_email and then call visit_in_email.  Example:

```
open_email('jdoe@gmail.com')
visit_in_email('Confirm my account')
expect(page).to have_content('Your email address has been successfully confirmed.')
```

The address used in the open_email call is the "to" field.

Hope this helps.